# Tant que + subjonctif

Tags: grammaire, subjonctif, mode-grammatical, paroles-de-chanson

J'ai lu partout que l'on suit toujours l'expression « tant que » de l'indicatif quand elle signifie « so long as ». Cependant, j'écoutais [une chanson](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f1Wujpc7dVM) dont j'ai écrit les paroles ci-dessous :

> Tant qu'on rêve encore
>   Que nos yeux s'étonnent encore
>   Rien n'est perdu
>   Tant qu'on rêve encore
>   Que jamais personne s'endorme
>   Et ne rêve plus
>   Jamais plus

Précisément, le vers « (tant) Que jamais personne s'endorme » m'embrouille. Pourquoi a-t-on utilisé le subjonctif « s'endorme » dans ce cas ?

Comment: Je préfère entendre le plus correct « Que jamais personne ne s'endorme » mais la différence est imperceptible.

Comment: @jlliagre En effet, le "ne" doit être avalé pour que le nombre de syllabes corresponde à "Que nos yeux s'étonnent encore"

Comment: Pour moi cela devrait être "Que jamais personne ne s'endort"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ce n'est pas *tant que* qui demande le subjonctif (son verbe est *rêve* ici) ; c'est *que* qui sert d'impératif de la troisième personne :

*que jamais personne s'endorme* = "let/may no one ever fall asleep again."

C'est comme *qu'il pleuve !* = "let it rain!"

Comment: Je n'ai jamais entendu "C'est comme qu'il pleuve", et le fait que cela veuille dire "let it rain" me perturbe d'autant plus... est-ce une expression régionale, où vis-je simplement dans une grotte ? :)

Comment: C'est « c'est comme "qu'il pleuve" », pas « C'est comme qu'il pleuve » :-)

Comment: J'aurais pu dire *qu'il neige* mais le subjonctif n'y est pas évident.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Pour moi *s'étonner* et *s'endormir* sont au subjonctif car on a ici la construction (bizarrement absente du TLFi) *rêver que + subj.* signifiant souhaiter, espérer (dans le sens voir en songe, *rêver que* est suivit de l'indicatif).